# Bootstrap 5 Ratio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently looking at bootrap 5 ratio as seen here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/

By default there are four classes:

```
.ratio-1x1
.ratio-4x3
.ratio-16x9
.ratio-21x9
```

I was wondering if I got this correctly when it comes to the dimension of each ratio.
For instance:

- **ratio-1x1**:  1080 x 1080 pixel
- **ratio-4x3**: sized at 1024 x 768 pixels
- **ratio-16x9**: 1920 x 1080 pixels
- **ratio-21x9**:  2560×1080 pixels

Is this correct? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. These are _ratios_, so what does this have to do with any fixed(?) sizes?